# Creating a symmetric matrix

Tags: vba, excel, matrix

I want to learn how to create a symmetric matrix in VBA. For example in the first step I want to choose `Range("C3:I3")` then copy to the `Range("B4:B10")`. In the second stage it should choose `Range("D4:I4")` then copy to the `Range("C5:C10")`. It should go on like that.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. Excel does not have a command to copy a range of 8 cells into a single cell. What are you trying to do? Edit your question and provide more detail. Post  a comment when you've done that.

Comment: i do not want to paste to one cell (B4) it is only starting point of the copy process. If it is not clear i want to paste it to Range("B4:B11")

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some code to do it. Your selected cell must be within the range of numbers.

**1. If the diagonal line is empty.**

### [image] ► [image]

The code:

```
Sub making_symmetric_matrix()

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Selection.CurrentRegion
Dim rngStart As Range
Set rngStart = Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column - 1)

For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    For j = i To rng.Columns.Count
        rngStart.Offset(j, i - 1).Value = rngStart.Offset(i - 1, j).Value
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

**2. If the diagonal line is not empty.**

### [image] ► [image]

The code:

```
Sub making_symmetric_matrix2()

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Selection.CurrentRegion
Dim rngStart As Range
Set rngStart = Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column)

For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    For j = i To rng.Columns.Count
        rngStart.Offset(j - 1, i - 1).Value = rngStart.Offset(i - 1, j - 1).Value
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA to do that. Select the cells and copy them. Select the top cell of the target range, use Paste Special and tick the box for "Transpose".

If you really need VBA to do this, you definitely don't need a loop as suggested in the other post. Just use the transpose option in the VBA code. For a large data set this will be a lot faster than looping through each cell.

```
    Range("C3:I3").Copy
    Range("B4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
```

Comment: Since my data is large it is hard to use same code for each cell it is why i need a loop.